# Classe não compila ao utilizar a nova feature 'Optional' do java 8

Tags: java-8, play-framework

Boa tarde

Estou utilizando play 2.5.4 com java 8 v01.08.91
E ao utilizar algumas features do java 8 como a classe 'Optional'
com o métodos 'ifPresent' , 'isPresent' ou 'get' é apresentado o seguinte erro ao compilar as classes java

```
"java.lang.ClassCastException: javassist.bytecode.InterfaceMethodrefInfo cannot be cast to javassist.bytecode.MethodrefInfo"
```

Especificamente, este é o trecho do código que da problema:

```
Optional<AppMobileWrapper> lastSend = appsWrapper.stream()
            .max(Comparator.comparing(f -> f.changeDate));

    lastSend.ifPresent(appMobileWrapper -> {
        returnWrapper.lastDate = DateUtils.currentDateNoTimeZoneString(appMobileWrapper.changeDate);
    });
```

Já tentei fazer de tudo, estou a horas procurando uma solução.
Minha versão do play está atualizada, versão do java atualizada, variáveis de ambiente estão ok e até tentei adicionar a dependência do javassist atualizada nas dependências do sbt e mesmo assim não funciona de jeito nenhum.
Alguém passou por esse problema?

Answer (score 1):

Depois de um upgrade no play/java, resolvi problema parecido seguindo as instruções descritas [nessa issue do projeto](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/issues/5127). No meu caso, atualizei o javassist em `project/plugins.sbt`:

`libraryDependencies += "org.javassist" % "javassist" % "3.20.0-GA"`

Uma vez que o mesmo seria usado por um plugin do sbt em tempo de compilação e não em runtime.

Comment: Já tentei isso, e não resolveu ;/

Comment: eu adicionei 
"org.javassist" % "javassist" % "3.20.0-GA"
no meu **plugins.sbt** e funcionou.
Mas realmente eu não entendi a diferença pro que eu já faço, hoje eu tenho um arquivo **.scala** separado com todas as dependências do meu projeto, importo no meu **build.sbt** e concateno na construção dos projetos, e isso não funcionava quando eu adicionava o **javassist**.
Consegue me explicar qual a diferença do **plugins.sbt** pro **build.sbt**?

Comment: @RodrigoWippel vejo isso como uma esquizofrenia do sbt :) o `project/plugins.sbt` é usado para definir os plugins e as dependências dos mesmos. No meu caso (e que parece o seu também) o `javassist` seria uma dependência de um plugin do sbt utilizada somente em tempo de compilação. O que não entendo é o motivo pelo qual nós precisamos declarar essa dependência manualmente, uma vez que nosso projeto (declarado em `build.sbt`) não depende diretamente dela.

Comment: Pois é né! Enfim, obrigado pela ajuda!